# Microsoft Access Web App Lookup fields not displaying in List View

Tags: listview, ms-access, lookupfield

I have built a Web Application in Microsoft Access.

For some reason, in my list views, the fields that are lookup fields are not displaying at all.

They do display properly in the datasheet view.

While this doesn't necessarily hurt the functionality of my app in particular, I cannot turn it in with it broken this way. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong that these fields are not displaying?

I have two lookup fields, one for company name and one for bundle name.

Any help is most appreciated -- I've spent all day trying to find an answer with no luck!